# Passing an object to a method and then calling an extenstion method on that object

Tags: c#, extension-methods, linq-to-objects, byref

I was working on a method yesterday and ran into something strange, here is dumbed down version of the code: Basically  the problem is that the OrderBy applied in the Bar.PopulateList method is not persisting.

```
class Foo
{
    List MyObjects;

    public void PopulateMyObjects()
    {
        //Items are added to my list but the OrderBy is not persisting.
        Bar.PopulateList(MyObjects);
    }
}

class Bar
{
   public static int PopulateList(List theList)
   {
       foreach(var in WebSerbiceCall)
       {
            theList.Add(var);
       }
       // the OrderBy call only sorts 'theList' in the context of this method.
       // When I return from this method theList has been populated but the Ordering has 
       // reverted back to the order that the items were added to the list.
       theList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID);
       return theList.Count;
   }
}
```

Now if I update the code and add the ref keyword as per below it all works:
e.g.  public static int PopulateList(ref List theList)
and Bar.PopulateList(ref MyObjects);

Can anyone enlighten me? I thought objects were always passed by ref? Is it the fact that OrderBy is an extension method?

Thanks, Cian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the `OrderBy` call does not actually mutate `theList` in any way. It instead returns a new `IEnumerable<object>` which is ordered.  Hence this is why you do not see the affects of the call outside the method, it's simply not changing the object.

Using the `OrderBy` method creates a new value and hence if you want the calling function to be aware of this new value it must be returned in some manner.  The most common places are in the return value or in a `ref`/`out` param.

```
public static int PopulateList(ref List<object> theList) {
  ...
  theList = theList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I thought that too, so then I tried: theList = thisList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID).ToList(); as mentioned by Matthew below but that did not work either. Also why does adding the ref keyword work?

Comment: @CianM that still won't work unless `theList` is an `out` or `ref` param.  Without that you'd just be modifying the copy of the reference within the method.

Comment: Thanks for that! I understand now, for anyone else who is confused by this I found a great article with pretty pictures to help: http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/01/parameter-passing-in-c.html

Comment: What's the advantage of `theList = theList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID).ToList();` over `theList.Sort(obj => obj.ID)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
return theList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID).Count;
```

(I was going to add an explaination but @jaredPar has explained it)

Comment: Doesn't the ordered enumerable have the same number of elements as the unsorted list?

Comment: There is code above the OrderBy that reads: theList.Add(var); So I don't think that that can be assumed.

Comment: But OrderBy doesn't add or remove any elements, so `theList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID).Count()` should equal `theList.Count`, no?

Answer (score 1):

C# passes arguments by value, it's just that the value of a reference type is the pointer to it's memory location.  The problem you are having is this line:

```
theList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID);
```

You're not assigning the result:

```
theList = thisList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, This is what I orginally thought too but it still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) extension method does not sort the [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) in-place. It returns an [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) that returns the elements of the list in sorted order.

Use the [List<T>.Sort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) to sort the [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) in-place.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the `ref` keyword then the parameter passed is a new reference to the same object.  It is 'passed by reference' in a sense but you have to think about it a bit differently.

Other answers are correct, `OrderBy` does not perform in place and instead returns an ordered collection.  But if you set your parameter to the result, then you change the value of the parameter (the reference) to point to the new collection, rather than changing the underlying object itself.

For example,

```
theList = thisList.OrderBy(obj => obj.ID).ToList();
```

takes `theList`, orders it and then creates a new List.  Then the value of `theList` - which is a reference to a list - is changed to point to the newly created (ordered) list.  The original reference, created outside this method, still points to the original unordered list.

The reason is that whenever you call `.ToList()` you actually create a new list.  When you use the `ref` keyword, you pass the actual variable containing the reference to the list, rather than create a new reference to the same list.

Comment: Thank You. Thats a really concise explanation.